# How are map tiles created?

Tags: tiles, image, imagery, mapping, openmaptiles

I have recently been diving into the world of maps and I got interested to know how map services work, like Google, Mapbox, Leaflet, Open Street Maps and many others. I was confused about the difference between them, however, after doing some research, I now understand the difference between them. Leaflet, for example, is the map program that displays the map, but this program needs a map data. The library makes a call to a mapping API, say Open Street Map, which is the map data itself. Some companies offer both, the map data and the map program, like Mapbox.

Leaflet makes a call to OSM with the Zoom and coords X and Y, the API then, retrieves the respective image accordingly like this one:

[image]

I know how it works but I don't know how those map tiles are created but I believe it takes a lot of them to compose a map, especially when there are map tiles with different styles. I wonder how much time and effort is required create those map tile images.

How are map tile images created? (Is there any specific program to do it? Is it manually created?)

Comment: There are different ways to achieve this goal. One is described in this tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/creating_basemaps_with_qtiles.html You find other ansers googleing for `create map tiles`

Comment: This should help https://macwright.com/2012/05/15/how-web-maps-work.html

Comment: That helps, thank you, but how those map tile images are created? We have to use specfic programs like in the tutorial that @Babel sent or there are other options? Are they individually created? If so, it must be a really long and tiring job since one has to create images for the whole world, sometimes with different styles.

Comment: yes there are programs to create them. gdal2tiles, tilemaker, osm2vectortiles are few tools I know of but I am unaware of the internals of those. Maybe somebody else can take from here.

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is (Is there a specific program: Yes; Is it manually created: No) And yes, it is a long job, esp. when taking into account that -for instance- OSM has 20 separate zoom levels, and [many edits](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Stats) daily worldwide. There is a number of 'rendering-servers' that are continuously updating tiles. (Then again, there are many tiles such as [this one](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/7/52/46.png) that are part of the ocean, and are just a blue square). If you want to know about rendering internals, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I was just literally jut curious to know how all those map tiles, from every part of the world with different styles and  zoom levels were created. Now it's a bit more clear.